# How to get Access Token once user successfully logged in to facebook using URI association in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8, uri

I go through the Facebook documentation for login through Facebook in Windows phone 8 application.I am using login dialog from myapp by launching the following URI association:

```
fbconnect://authorize?client_id={your-facebook-app-id}&scope={permissions- requested}&redirect_uri=msft-{ProductID}://authorize
```

User gets authorized using facebook application installed in the device.The problem i am facing is that,once user gets successfully logged in, they will be sent to your app, along with an access token.Can anyone tell me how i can retrieve this access token?

As per facebook documentation they mentioned:

> If someone successfully logs in, the URI association of your app will
>   be automatically triggered, meaning they will be sent to your app,
>   along with an access token:

```
msft-{ProductID}://authorize/?access_token={user-access-token}&expires_in={expiration-time-of-token}
```

I am registering Uri association for my app like this in WMAppMAnifest.xml file

```
<Extensions>      
  <Protocol Name="msft-31fbf137141a439a9c4e15e73826e0f6" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Can anyone tell me how i can retrieve this access token?Which method will trigger back to retrieve Access Token?

Comment: any success ? , I am facing same issue.